# tensorflow speaker recognition

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow

Can someone please tell me if it is possible to make speaker recognition using tensorflow? I am extracting MFCC data from audio file using librosa and by that I want to recognize speaker. Any suggestions or links on how to implement that?

Answer (score 0):

Check this repo -> https://github.com/pannous/tensorflow-speech-recognition
You can view the speaker_classifier_tflearn.py and get a feeling on how it works.